# An effective way to select squares by mouse clicks from a board (Python 3.X. tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking for a more effective way to select squares from a rectangular board by mouse clicks.

While working I have come up with this simple implementation:

```
import tkinter as tk


def square_selector(event):
    if 1 <= event.x <= 199 and 1 <= event.y <= 199:
        print('This is square 1')
    elif 1 <= event.x <= 199 and 201 <= event.y <= 399:
        print('This is square 2')
    elif 1 <= event.x <= 199 and 401 <= event.y <= 599:
        print('This is square 3')
    elif 201 <= event.x <= 399 and 1 <= event.y <= 199:
        print('This is square 4')
    elif 201 <= event.x <= 399 and 201 <= event.y <= 399:
        print('This is square 5')
    elif 201 <= event.x <= 399 and 401 <= event.y <= 599:
        print('This is square 6')
    elif 401 <= event.x <= 599 and 1 <= event.y <= 199:
        print('This is square 7')
    elif 401 <= event.x <= 599 and 201 <= event.y <= 399:
        print('This is square 8')
    elif 401 <= event.x <= 599 and 401 <= event.y <= 599:
        print('This is square 9')
    else:
        pass


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(height=600, width=600)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_line(0, 200, 600, 200)
canvas.create_line(0, 400, 600, 400)
canvas.create_line(200, 0, 200, 600)
canvas.create_line(400, 0, 400, 600)

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', square_selector)

root.mainloop()
```

This looks okay (at least to me) with a 3x3 board, but it would get quite huge when designing a bigger board. Could anyone suggest me a better idea for doing this or at least point in a good direction? Thanks!

Comment: Does this need to be on a canvas?

Comment: Generally, no. I was looking for something like @Jacques Gaudin idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def square_selector(event):
    sq_num = (event.x // 200) * 3 + (event.y // 200) + 1
    print("This is square {0}".format(sq_num))
```

`//` is the integer division and it will give you the coordinates of the click event on the square grid which you then use to produce the square number.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need a canvas I think a better approach would be to build labels instead.

You will need a 1x1 pixel image to make this work as the size of a labels by default is based on the font size instead of pixel size. By adding a 1x1 pixel image to the label we can then define height and width by pixels.

I also prefer to use a list to store the labels and other variables you may wish to store alongside the label.

This is scales dynamically as well.

You do not need to apply the numbers to the box I just did that for visual representation.

```
import tkinter as tk


def square_selector(square):
    print(square)

root = tk.Tk()
label_list = []
counter = 1
img = tk.PhotoImage(file='1x1.png')

grid_size = 4
box_size = 100

for x in range(grid_size):
    for y in range(grid_size):
        label_list.append(tk.Label(root, text=counter, image=img, width=box_size, height=box_size,
                                   compound='center', borderwidth=1, relief="solid"))
        label_list[-1].grid(row=x, column=y)
        label_list[-1].bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, c=counter: square_selector(c))
        counter += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: This is also an interesting idea! Thanks!